# Can't create instance from java sdk

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I am trying to create an OCI instance with the Java SDK. I am getting an error in routeRules.

When I commented the following line, I was able to create an instance. But in that machines route is not enabled.

`addInternetGatewayToRouteTable(vcnClient, compartmentId, vcn.getDefaultRouteTableId(), internetGateway);`

https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/CreateInstanceExample.java

```
Exception in thread "main" com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (400, InvalidParameter, false) routeRules[0].networkEntityId may not be null (opc-request-id: 6BC8A182852240F8AFFD1EB279CFF901/AD5BF82603D64DA298976FCFE83871F6/9398B04078B0435A8FA68FEA7307CC99)
        at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ResponseHelper.throwIfNotSuccessful(ResponseHelper.java:120)
        at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ResponseConversionFunctionFactory$ValidatingParseResponseFunction.apply(ResponseConversionFunctionFactory.java:86)
        at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.ResponseConversionFunctionFactory$ValidatingParseResponseFunction.apply(ResponseConversionFunctionFactory.java:82)
        at com.oracle.bmc.core.internal.http.UpdateRouteTableConverter$1.apply(UpdateRouteTableConverter.java:70)
        at com.oracle.bmc.core.internal.http.UpdateRouteTableConverter$1.apply(UpdateRouteTableConverter.java:55)
        at com.oracle.bmc.core.VirtualNetworkClient.updateRouteTable(VirtualNetworkClient.java:3325)
        at CreateInstanceExample.addInternetGatewayToRouteTable(CreateInstanceExample.java:295)
        at CreateInstanceExample.main(CreateInstanceExample.java:146)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in the code, you can replace `destination` in the `addInternetGatewayToRouteTable(..)` method

```
        RouteRule internetAccessRoute =
                RouteRule.builder()
                        .cidrBlock("0.0.0.0/0")
                        .destination(internetGateway.getId())
                        .build();
```

in line 295 with `networkEntityId`:

```
        RouteRule internetAccessRoute =
                RouteRule.builder()
                        .cidrBlock("0.0.0.0/0")
                        .networkEntityId(internetGateway.getId())
                        .build();
```

You can see from the [REST APIs here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/RouteTable/CreateRouteTable) which parameters are required to create a route rule in a route table.

The example seems to be based on a deprecated version of calling the RouteRule builder.